# Image VIew problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can i remove an ImageView added on a dynamically created UIView, so that i can add another ImageView on my UIView.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically" ?

Comment: dynamically means at run time..m not using xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is probably with tags. So...

```
UIImageView *removeMe = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
removeMe.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage.png"];
removeMe.tag = 1;
[theView addSubview:removeMe];
[removeMe release]; //theView now retains it!
```

...then later:

```
UIImageView *removalTarget = (UIImageView *)[theView viewWithTag:1];
[removalTarget removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 4):

You either add a tag for that UIImageView and find it based on tag or loop throughout the subviews and look for an object of class UIImageView containing the image you need to change.